# Mathematical operation in one single input

Tags: python, math

I'm a python beginner and i'm trying to make a calculator that instead of asking the user enter first number than an operator and than antoher number to return the result, the user can be able to input like for example 3 * 3 in one single input so the computer returns 9.

```
num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
op = input("Enter an operator: ")
num2 = float(input("Enter another number: "))

if op == "+":
 print(num1 + num2)
elif op == "-":
 print(num1 - num2)
elif op == "*":
 print(num1 * num2)
elif op == "/":
 print(num1 / num2)

else:
 print(" Enter a valid operator...")
```

Comment: There's plenty to say about this, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: The unsafe way is to use `eval()`.

Comment: Eval is highly unsafe and not recommended at all. Especially for what you are trying to do with your calculator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you are looking to get the complete input from the user in one go, so that your calculator works without asking for inputs 3 times.

> NOTE: Using `eval` is highly unsafe and is very much discouraged. Your approach is absolutely fine and doesn't need `eval()`. The question you are trying to solve is not related to `eval()` to begin with. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice#:%7E:text=Using%20eval%20is%20weak%2C%20not,which%20must%20be%20clearly%20understood.).

Try this -

```
num1, op, num2 = input('Enter equation with spaces in-between: ').split(' ')
num1, num2 = float(num1), float(num2)

if op == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)
elif op == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
elif op == "*":
    print(num1 * num2)
elif op == "/":
    print(num1 / num2)

else:
    print(" Enter a valid operator...")
```

```
enter equation: 3 * 3
9.0
```

The `str.split(' ')` will break the string input into 3 parts based on the spaces. You can then store these in variables, convert the `num1` and `num2` into `float` and use your function.

Answer (score 0):

The `eval` function may help:

```
inputstr = '3 * 3'
print(eval(inputstr))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the input will be completely formatted, use `eval()`

```
s = input("Enter an expression: ")
try:
    print(eval(s))
except:
    print("Enter a valid expression...")
```

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, the unsafe way is to use `eval()`, but a safe way could be

```
vals = input("Enter an operation: ").split()
num1 = float(vals[0])
op = vals[1]
num2 = float(vals[2])

# The rest of your code as you've written it
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.split()`.

This works assuming there's a space separating each value and operator, and there are only two values involved.

```
def equation():
    string = input("Enter an equation: ")
    #this splits the input string into its parts and puts them into a list
    string_as_list = string.split(' ')
    print(string_as_list)
    
    num1 = float(string_as_list[0])
    op = string_as_list[1]
    num2 = float(string_as_list[2])
    if op == "+":
        result = num1 + num2
    elif op == "-":
        result = num1 - num2
    elif op == "*":
        result = num1 * num2
    elif op == "/":
        result = num1 / num2
    
    return result
```